# Docker AutoStartup service NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx, service, dockerfile

I want to AutoStartup Service NGINX in Docker Containers,

I tried adding this code in DOCKERFILE FILE, but the service doesn't auto start.

```
RUN service nginx start
CMD service nginx start
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that this service/Daemon is going to run in background.

Go through following article for more information
**[How to Run a Daemon Service in the Foreground](https://dzone.com/articles/run-daemon-service-in-foreground)**

Quick workaround is to replace CMD or ENTRYPOINT with
 You must figure out the start command in order to run in the foreground.

```
(Note: Daemon Service = Binary + Configuration + Initscript.)

To run the process in the foreground, we just need these two ingredients:

Binary: bash -x /etc/init.d/XXX start.
Here, -x instructs shell to display verbose output. Should be easy to figure out binary path. Another trick is _”ps -ef | grep $PROCESS_PATTERN”_.
Configuration: Typically speaking, we can dig out from console output of bash -x. Sometimes, it’s just too long to read. Figure out the process ID and the list environment from cat /proc/$pid/environ.
A lot of decent services refuse to run as root because of security concerns. Here is how to impersonate other users with root.
```

So in your case executable command should be

```
CMD ["bash", "-x", "/etc/init.d/nginx","start"]
```

Or tweek it accordingly.
In case you need more help ,let me know in comments section.